# Loading data into a textbox

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

This is a fairly simple question, though I am unsure of exactly how to go about it. I'm doing a query on a database, then inserting the pulled value into a textbox. However the query could return a null value, here is my problem. If the query returns a null then the textbox should display 19. I'm unsure of how to check the returned data to determine if null was returned so that 19 can be inserted into the textbox. here is my code (it works putting the returned value into the textbox its missing the check for null/add 19)

```
using (test1 ds = new test1())
{
    DataTable dt = ds.dataset.Tables[0];
    List<string> coolList = new List<string>();

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        coolList.Add(row[0].ToString());
    }

    textBox7.Text = string.Join(" ", coolList);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: thank you, don't know all of the rules yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better not use null. Simple write in your SQL: `SELECT IsNull(YourColumn, 19) as YourColumn FROM WhatEver`. Than you have solved your problem directly in sql.

Comment: my sql is a little shaky so for example,  if my select is , SELECT Cat FROM Dog, i would change it to SELECT IsNull(Cat, 19) as Cat From dog?

Comment: That depends on the data-type of Cat. If cat is a varchar you should use: SELECT IsNull(Cat, '19') as Cat From dog. If Cat is an integer, let the single quotes away.

Answer (score 2):

```
string rowString = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(row[0].ToString()) ? row[0].ToString() : "19";
coolList.Add(rowString);
```

You can use `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` instead if you're using .NET 4 or newer.

Comment: thanks this is what i was originally looking for, but the sql is making it easier. however i am using this piece elsewhere for another issue i had so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a `List<string>` , you can use [LINQ to DataSet/DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977(v=vs.110).aspx) like:

```
textBox7.Text = string.Join(" ",
    dt.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(r => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Field<string>(0))
            ? "19"
            : r.Field<string>(0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ISNULL is whatcha need to handle this.